# Get rid of rows with duplicate attributes in R

Tags: r, duplicates, dataframe

I have a big dataframe with columns such as:

```
ID, time, OS, IP
```

Each row of that dataframe corresponds to one entry. Within that dataframe for some **IDs** several entries (rows) exist. I would like to get rid of those multiple rows (obviously the other attributes will differ for the same ID). Or put different: I only want one single entry (row) for each ID.

When I use `unique` on the ID column, I only receive the levels (or each unique ID), but I want to keep the other attributes as well.
I have tried to use `apply(x,2,unique(data$ID))`, but this does not work either.

Comment: You have to define what do you want to do with the other attributes for observations with the same ID when the don't agree.

Comment: well, i would like to see the OS distribution of the users...
So when I have the dataframe with only one entry per user, Id do: mytable <- table(dataset$os.name) and do some plotting afterwards...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
subset(data,!duplicated(data$ID))
```

Should do the trick

Comment: This will work if you don't have any heuristic in mind for how to select the other data.  Seems like a very strange use case to me...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep one row for each ID, but there is different data on each row, then you need to decide on some logic to discard the additional rows.  For instance:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 2, 3), time=1:4, OS="Linux")
df
  ID time    OS
1  1    1 Linux
2  2    2 Linux
3  2    3 Linux
4  3    4 Linux
```

Now I will keep the maximum time value and the last OS value:

```
library(plyr)
unique(ddply(df, .(ID), function(x) data.frame(ID=x[,"ID"], time=max(x$time), OS=tail(x$OS,1))))
  ID time    OS
1  1    1 Linux
2  2    3 Linux
4  3    4 Linux
```