# Find the duplicated rows of a dataframe and which original row the duplicated row is corresponding in R

Tags: r, duplicates

My data frame looks like:

```
 data <- data.frame(a=c(3,1,2,2,2,3),b=c(3,1,1,2,2,3))

 duplicated(data)

 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

What I want is not only the logical string to indicate which row is duplicating, but also which original row the duplicated row is corresponding. In the example above, the fifth row is the duplicate of the fourth row in the original dataframe and the sixth row is the duplicate of the first row in the original dataframe. So I want a index vector like:

```
   NA NA NA NA 4 1
```

(NA indicates non-duplicating row).

My naive approach is:

```
  dupTF <- duplicated(data)
  DupDat <- data[dupTF,]
  index0 <- rep(NA,nrow(DupDat))
  for (i in 1 : nrow(DupDat))
  {
     for (j in 1 : nrow(data))
        {
          if(all(data[j,] == DupDat[i,])) break;
        }
       index0[i] <- j
   }
  index <- rep(NA,length(dupTF))
  index[dupTF]<- index0
  index
  [1] NA NA NA NA  4  1
```

However, this approach is not ideal because it go through loop over all the data...

Comment: Here is a previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759394/get-rid-of-rows-with-duplicate-attributes-in-r) to this question.

Comment: @User7598 I am afraid they are not answering my question. These previous answers are about how to return the non duplicated rows of dataframe. My question is about how to return the INDEX of the original dataset that duplicated rows are corresponding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd likely use **data.table**, since its `.I` and `.N` variables (available from within each `by` group) make this so straightforward:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(data)
dt[, XX:=c(NA, rep(.I[1], .N-1)), by=c("a","b")][,XX]
# [1] NA NA NA NA  4  1
```

Comment: I did not know about data.table. Thank you.

Comment: Could you tell me what .I is referring to?

Comment: @ThePrincess -- For each group of rows, `.I` gives the row indices -- relative to the entire data.frame -- of those rows. So, for example, for the group of rows with both `a=3` and `b=3`, (i.e. rows 1 and 5), `.I` is `c(1,5)`. `.I[1]` thus returns the index of the first occurrence of a row in that group.